# 2 * ?...?2 = 2?...?. Чему равно минимальное такое ?...?2

Tags: c++, c, массивы, циклы, математика

Некоторое натуральное число заканчивается на двойку. Если ее переставить на первое место, то число удвоится. Какое минимальное число было изначально?

Программа очень долго компилируется, может если я сделал что-то не так, кто-нибудь заметит.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
int num, plu;
int getDigitAmount(int n) {
    int c = 1;
    while ( n /= 10)
        c++;

            switch (c) {
                case 1: plu = 20;
                    break;
                case 2: plu = 200;
                    break;
                case 3: plu = 2000;
                    break;
                case 4: plu = 20000;
                    break;
                case 5: plu = 200000;
                    break;
                case 6: plu = 2000000;
                    break;
                case 7: plu = 20000000;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
    plu = 0;
    c = 1;
    return c;
    }


    int main(){
        num = 0;
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));


        for (int a = 0, b = 1;a<b ; a++ ) {

            for (int i = 0, l = 1; i<l; i++) {
                num = rand()%100000;
                if(num%10!=2){
                    num = rand()%100000;
                }
                else if(num%10==2) {
                    l+=100;
                    break;

                }
                l++;
                b++;
            }


        cout << num << endl;
        getDigitAmount(num);

            if ((num / 10) * 2 != (num / 10)+plu) {
                b++;
            }
            else if ((num / 10) * 2 == (num/10)+plu && (num/10)>2){
                cout << num << " | "<< num / 10 << " | "<<endl;
                cout << (num / 10) * 2 << "  ||  "<<(num / 10) + plu<< endl;
                int z = (num/10) * 2;
                cout << z <<endl;
                break;
            }
        }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Компилируется или выполняется?

Comment: Вообще-то число, отвечающее указанным требованиям, состоит из 18 цифр... вряд ли оно в int поместится... да и добраться до него инкрементами - это очень оптимистично.

Comment: Выполняется ооовер долго.

Comment: Есть способ построить нужное число цифра за цифрой используя умножение в столбик.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Решение

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int factor;
    int least_digit;
    if (!(std::cin >> factor >> least_digit)) {
        return 1;
    }
    int p = least_digit;
    do {
        p = 10 * (p % factor) + p / factor;
        std::cout << p % 10;
    } while (p != least_digit);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror tricky-multiplication.cpp
>
> $ echo 2 2 | ./a.out
> 105263157894736842
>
> $ echo 6 9 | ./a.out
> 1525423728813559322033898305084745762711864406779661016949
> ```

### Обоснование

*в формулах ниже `%` - взятие остатка от деления, `/` - деление нацело.*

Искомое число `X` можно отыскать при помощи умножения в столбик. Обозначим `f` - множитель, `d(i)` - цифры `X`, `c(i)` - переносы при умножении, `e(i)` - цифры произведения `f * X`. Тогда

> ```
> d(1) - задано в условии
> c(1) = 0
> e(i) = (f * d(i) + c(i)) % 10 - очередная цифра произведения
> c(i+1) = (f * d(i) + c(i)) / 10 - перенос в следующий разряд
> d(i+1) = e(i) - из условия задачи
> ```

Условий достаточно чтобы из пары `d(i), c(i)` получить пару `d(i+1), c(i+1)`. То есть, мы можем цифра за цифрой восcтановить `X`.

Обозначим `p(i) = f * d(i) + c(i)`. Тогда

> ```
> p(1) = d(1)
> p(i+1) = f * (p(i) % 10) + p(i) / 10
> d(i) = p(i) / f
> ```

Зная `p(i)` можно вычислить `p(i+1)`. Оказывается что эта операция обратима. Заметим что `p(i) / 10 < f`:

> ```
> p(i) = f * d(i) + c(i) <= f * 9 + c(i) < f * 9 + f = 10 * f
> ```

Тогда верно что

> ```
> p(i) % 10 = p(i+1) / f
> p(i) / 10 = p(i+1) % f
> ```

Откуда

> ```
> 10 * (p(i+1) % f) + p(i+1) / f = p(i)
> ```

Последняя формула позволяет восстанавливать цифры `X` в порядке от старших к младшим, что удобно для печати. Начинать надо с `p(n) = d(1)`.

### Забавный факт

В таблице ниже если множитель один и тот же, то длина числа одна и та же. Кроме `f = 5`, `d(1) = 7` который короче своих соседей. Почему?

> ```
> 1 1: 1
> 1 2: 2
> 1 3: 3
> 1 4: 4
> 1 5: 5
> 1 6: 6
> 1 7: 7
> 1 8: 8
> 1 9: 9
>
> 2 2: 105263157894736842
> 2 3: 157894736842105263
> 2 4: 210526315789473684
> 2 5: 263157894736842105
> 2 6: 315789473684210526
> 2 7: 368421052631578947
> 2 8: 421052631578947368
> 2 9: 473684210526315789
>
> 3 3: 1034482758620689655172413793
> 3 4: 1379310344827586206896551724
> 3 5: 1724137931034482758620689655
> 3 6: 2068965517241379310344827586
> 3 7: 2413793103448275862068965517
> 3 8: 2758620689655172413793103448
> 3 9: 3103448275862068965517241379
>
> 4 4: 102564
> 4 5: 128205
> 4 6: 153846
> 4 7: 179487
> 4 8: 205128
> 4 9: 230769
>
> 5 5: 102040816326530612244897959183673469387755
> 5 6: 122448979591836734693877551020408163265306
> 5 7: 142857
> 5 8: 163265306122448979591836734693877551020408
> 5 9: 183673469387755102040816326530612244897959
>
> 6 6: 1016949152542372881355932203389830508474576271186440677966
> 6 7: 1186440677966101694915254237288135593220338983050847457627
> 6 8: 1355932203389830508474576271186440677966101694915254237288
> 6 9: 1525423728813559322033898305084745762711864406779661016949
>
> 7 7: 1014492753623188405797
> 7 8: 1159420289855072463768
> 7 9: 1304347826086956521739
>
> 8 8: 1012658227848
> 8 9: 1139240506329
>
> 9 9: 10112359550561797752808988764044943820224719
> ```

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ — просто для интереса озадачился другим обобщением этой задачки... Результаты никак не трактую.

Answer (score 8):

Зачем просто, если можно сложно, да?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned long long z = 2, x;

    for(int n = 1;;++n)
    {
        z = z*10;
        if ((z-4)%19==0)
        {
            x = (z-4)/19;
            break;
        }
    }
    z = z+x;
    cout << x*10+2 << endl;
    cout << z << endl;
}
```

Выводит ваши два числа. К счастью, `unsigned long long` хватает...

Математика тут такая - пусть это число - x и справа 2, т.е. его значение x*10+2. Если перенести 2 влево - будем иметь 2*10<sup>n</sup>+x для какого-то n. И оно равно 2*(x*10+2)= 20x+4. Так что 2*10<sup>n</sup> = 19x+4 - все, ищем такое n, при котором 2*10<sup>n</sup>-4 делится на 19. Дальше писать не нужно?...

P.S. Блин, настолько же я стар, что помню те времена, когда информатикой занимались математики, а ЭВМ использовались для расчетов... :)

**Update** через два с лишним года.

Задача - в системе счисления `B` найти числа для всех цифр `1..B-1`, которые, будучи перенесены из конца в начало, дают увеличение числа в соответствующее цифре число раз.

Получилось:

В восьмеричной:

```
1  11
2  1042
3  10262054413
4  10204
5  1015
6  10127114202562304053446
7  10112362022474404517
```

В десятичной

```
1  11
2  105263157894736842
3  1034482758620689655172413793
4  102564
5  102040816326530612244897959183673469387755
6  1016949152542372881355932203389830508474576271186440677966
7  1014492753623188405797
8  1012658227848
9  10112359550561797752808988764044943820224719
```

В шестнадцатеричной

```
1  11
2  10842
3  10572620ae4c415c9882b93
4  104
5  1033d91d2a2067b23a5440cf6474a8819ec8e95
6  102b1da46
7  1024e6a17
8  1020408
9  101ca4b3055ee19
a  1019c2d14ee4a
b  101767dce434a9b
c  101571ed3c506b39a22d9218202ae3da78a0d673445b24304055c7b4f141ace688b6486080ab8f69e28359cd116c90c
d  1013c995a47babe74404f265691eeaf9d
e  10125e22708092f113840497889c2024bc44e
f  10112358e75d30336a0ab617909a3e202246b1ceba6066d4156c2f21347c40448d639d74c0cda82ad85e4268f880891ac73ae9819b5055b0bc84d1f
```

Comment: Да, вспоминается из хабра --  на собеседовании: "напишите программу, которая печатает сумму целых чисел от 1 до 100" -)

Comment: @avp Ну, может, там хотели что-то типа `template<unsigned int N>
unsigned int sum()
{
    return sum<N-1>()+N;
}

template<>
unsigned int sum<1>()
{
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << sum<100>() << endl;
}` ? :)

Comment: А вот и нет. Правильный ответ `puts("5050");`

Comment: Для единиц ответ `1`, не `11` если мы ищем минимальное число.

Comment: Отличная идея! Я не думал о других системах счисления, а это интересно. Как вы обсчитывали числа которые не помещаются в `unsigned long long`?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да сначала набросал "ужас, летящий на крыльях ночи" :), который примерно как у вас описано, работал — со строкой, а потом просто взял и воспользовался `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Для единиц можно трактовать двояко... Я все же предпочел считать что, если мы забираем последнюю цифру, то что-то все же остается — иначе мы ее не меняем, а оставляем на своем же месте. Но, понятно, это уже вопрос точности формулировки...

Comment: `36 10 10` заканчивается на `usa`: `103lylgjnkcu30atvsdmyp2i90whnd4ww37ir2pgy3eqo9mk984eua880svorod8iuoo2en2b13pkk2077x6x3b4po60lnrkr9xe50i1szaq9ts6f1i5exw6thcj94ig8tokgg1lrdjcqh1pdc4ta4m27f5440efudu6m9fcc17bj5ijusa`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Бывает :)